# Merge 2 lists with linq where at least one property has changed

Tags: c#, linq

```
var usersOld = new List<User>();
var userOld1 = new User { IsDisabled = true, IsLicenced = false, Id = 1 };
var userOld2 = new User { IsDisabled = true, IsLicenced = false, Id = 2 };
var userOld3 = new User { IsDisabled = true, IsLicenced = false, Id = 3 };
var userOld4 = new User { IsDisabled = true, IsLicenced = false, Id = 4 };

usersOld.Add(userOld1);
usersOld.Add(userOld2);
usersOld.Add(userOld3);
usersOld.Add(userOld4);

var usersToday = new List<User>();
var userNew1 = new User { IsDisabled = true, IsLicenced = true, Id = 1 };
var userNew2 = new User { IsDisabled = true, IsLicenced = false, Id = 2 };
var userNew3 = new User { IsDisabled = false, IsLicenced = false, Id = 3 };
var userNew4 = new User { IsDisabled = true, IsLicenced = true, Id = 4 };

usersToday.Add(userNew1);
usersToday.Add(userNew2);
usersToday.Add(userNew3);
usersToday.Add(userNew4);

var query = null;
```

How can I merge both lists into one list where at least one property hasChanged so the User is "dirty"

// According to my logic the users with id 1, 3 and 4 have changed in any of both properties. Note in real life there can and will
        // be more properties than these 2 properties.

Comment: Implementing `IEquatable<User>` in the class `User` could help.

Comment: Have you tried ObersvableCollection? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mephy says, implementing `IEquatable<User>` would make this simpler - at that point, you could just perform a join:

```
var changes = usersOld.Join(usersNew, o => o.Id, n => n.Id,
                            (o, n) => new { Old = o, New = n })
                      .Where(pair => !pair.Old.Equals(pair.New));
```

Then whenever you add a relevant property, you just need to change the `Equals` implementation to take account of that.

The result is a sequence of pairs - currently as an anonymous type, but you could use `Tuple<,>` if you wanted to return from a method.

Comment: I have heard of IEquatable already but never used it instead I used IEqualityComparer when I tried to .Intersect entities. Is IEquality really the right interface?

Comment: @Pascal: Well it makes sense if a `User` should be able to compare itself with another `User` in a uniform way. `IEqualityComparer` is usually used when you're trying to compare two objects of a *different* type, usually by some subset of properties. Of course it doesn't really matter in this case - you're calling `Equals` directly in my answer, so you can do what you like. It's just that `IEquatable<T>` would be an idiomatic approach.

Comment: Right you are Jon. I remember now I did different type intersecting over the id... Ok thanks!